# BCrypt comparing two hashes not equal

Tags: hash, go, passwords, bcrypt

I have this code:

u := models.Users{}

u = u.FindByEmail(login.Email)

password := []byte(login.Password)

hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword(password, bcrypt.DefaultCost)
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }

err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(hashedPassword, []byte(u.Password))
   fmt.Println(err)

I end up getting this error: crypto/bcrypt: hashedPassword is not the hash of the given password

However I previously saved my model to have the same hash as "admin", but when I run my application, it tells me it is not equal.

Answer (score 5):

Re-read the [docs](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt#CompareHashAndPassword) carefully.

CompareHashAndPassword compares a bcrypt hashed password with its possible plaintext equivalent. Returns nil on success, or an error on failure.

Basically, it is saying that you should compare the hash you have stored against the plain text password.

you probably want:

```
u := models.Users{}

u = u.FindByEmail(login.Email)

plainPassword := []byte(login.Password)
// Assumes that u.Password is the actual hash and that you didn't store plain text password.
err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(u.Password), plainPassword)

fmt.Println(err)
```

Comment: Just to add to this: two "new" bcrypt hashes for the same password won't be the same, as the salt used will be unique for that hash and set of parameters. Using the comparison function will use the same salt, params and constant-time compare it correctly.

Comment: It seems to not be working..

The current password in the database is: $2a$10$A/KM.HIbw3sdH79pML9Sv.MLvkWw3.Xbnxl7Gs

which is 'admin', but whenever I compare that in the code, it is always different. Would this be caused by the situation pointed above?

Comment: how are you storing the user's password?  you convert to []byte in your example, which makes me think as a string.  Did you base64 encode the password?  or did you store the binary directly in a column/field in your database? or was it simply you did string(bytesFromHash)?

Comment: yes, when you generate the hash, it is potentially different each time.  You can't do an == comparison on hashes which is why the CompareHashAndPassword function exists... what error are you getting?

Comment: The error I got was: crypto/bcrypt: hashedSecret too short to be a bcrypted password.

I am storing the password as what I receive from the function, verbatim.

Comment: are you sure the storage mechanism can store the raw bytes?  bcrypt produces plain old bytes.  Usually you would convert to hex or base64 encode them or something.